# Huge size core-data object

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, dataset, nsmanagedobject

I was trying to add 200k messages to a core data object for a proof of concept of a twitter app. This works well and my entities are added. I have a `UISearchBar` and a `UITableView` to display these. However, for every new 1000 object, my time seems to be increasing exponentially. Is this normal ? I expected `CoreData` to perform well for huge datasets. Do you have better suggestion to handling such huge dataset. I wonder, how `Dictionary apps` work.

My Console Output is here:

> -2012-03-26 22:19:28.126 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 1000
>   -2012-03-26 22:19:40.335 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 2000 
>   -2012-03-26 22:19:55.136 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 3000
>   -2012-03-26 22:20:18.569 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 4000
>     -2012-03-26 22:20:50.166 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 5000
>     -2012-03-26 22:21:30.284 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 6000
>     -2012-03-26 22:22:19.096 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 7000
>     -2012-03-26 22:23:16.091 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 8000
>     -2012-03-26 22:24:21.321 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 9000
>     -2012-03-26 22:25:35.017 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 10000
>     -2012-03-26 22:26:57.250 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 11000
>     -2012-03-26 22:28:27.563 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 12000
>     -2012-03-26 22:30:06.202 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 13000
>     -2012-03-26 22:31:52.645 TweetReader[3668:707] Done 14000

Here it is my code to save into `CoreData`:

```
for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 200000; i++) {

NSAutoreleasePool * myPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

Tweet *tweetie = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    tweetie.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%10d",i];
    tweetie.message =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%10d",i];
    // Save the context after 1000 objects.
    if (! (i % 1000)) {
        NSError *error;
        NSLog(@"Done %d",i); 
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        [myPool release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you complaining about the adding being slow, or working with the dataset once this is complete?

Comment: Also, you are creating a new autorelease pool for every iteration of the loop - that's a bad idea.

Comment: The adding being slow. It took almost 2 hours to 200k objects to be added on a actual iPhone 3gs.

Comment: After the adding, the UISearchBar and fetching works reasonably, though not as good as Dictionary apps i have seen.  Thanks for pointing at autorelease pool, i will change this and see if there are any timing improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which columns do you have indexed on your database? Have you tried locking the context while you add to see if it can optimise this (i.e. do the inserts transactionally?)

Core Data is notoriously bad at bulk inserts. The solution to this might just be to use sqlite directly - see this article for a real life case study of someone who had to do that : http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data

Comment: A very good article indeed. I read so much praise about core data over sqlite everywhere. This was kind of eye-opener.

Comment: I have no indexes (a plain core-data entity, with name & message). I will try locking the context (though i am not sure how to do this).

Comment: Thanks dean. The same things with Sqlite takes a only few seconds. This code can probably serve as an example for when Core data is not the right answer. I will still try optimizing this with core-data as much as i can and then post a better timing comparison vs. sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

hey if you have 200k messages, first find whats the optimum storing for the length of your each message. This would be trial and error , i found 3000 to be optimum . perform [save context] on every 3000 eg:

```
      for(i=0; i<num of objects;i++)
      { // form the object to be saved in context

      if(i%3000==0){ // save the num of records , optimum value
        NSError *error;
        NSLog(@"saved rec nu %d",i);
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return NO;
       }

        [context processPendingChanges];// most important thing , if not objects will 
              // keep adding in context and time would for insertion would drastically increase.
     }
        //for last set of the objects which are less than 3000
        NSError *error;
        NSLog(@"saved rec nu %d",i);
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return NO;



    }
```

Let me know if anything..